# Is there a way to show the tab tooltip immediately on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I keep >80 tabs open as I multi-task through various goals. A time comes when I need to bulk close multiple tabs. This is where the problem of tab-tooltip clicks in.

I don't want to open each tab (and wait for it to load from memory). Instead I just hover over the tab's title for the tooltip to show the name of the tab and then close it if it's not needed.

It takes almost 1 second for the tooltip to appear. Is there any way I can set this delay to 0 for Chrome?